# Get table alias from Zend_Db_Table_Select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-select, aliases

I'm working on an Active Record pattern (similar to RoR/Cake) for my Zend Framework library. My question is this: How do I figure out whether a select object is using an alias for a table or not?

```
$select->from(array("c" => "categories"));
```

**vs.**

```
$select->from("categories");
```

and I pass this to a "fetch" function which adds additional joins and whatnot to get the row relationships automatically...I want to add some custom sql; either "c.id" or "categories.id" based on how the user used the "from" method.

I know I can use

```
$parts = $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::FROM);
```

to get the from data as an array, and the table name or alias seems to be in "slot" 0 of said array. Will the table name or alias always be in slot zero? i.e. can I reliably use:

```
$tableNameOrAlias = $parts[0];
```

Sorry if this is convolute but hope you can help! :)

Comment: Just a hint, the proper name for what you call "slot" here is _index_. So array[0] is index 0, array['c'] is index 'c'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically, I would think that's how it should work. To be on the safe side, build a few dummy queries using a Select() and dump the part array using `print_r` or such.

I just performed this test, the alias is the array key, it is not a zero-based numeric array:

```
   $select = $this->db->select()->from(array("c" => "categories","d" => "dummies"));
   $parts = $select->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::FROM);
   echo '<pre>';
   print_r($parts);
   echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [c] => Array
        (
            [joinType] => inner join
            [schema] => 
            [tableName] => categories
            [joinCondition] => 
        )

)
```

So you would need to reference it as `$part["c"]`

Comment: Hmm, that's neat, but my issue is I don't know whether the user will pass a select object with an aliased table or just the table name, so I can't reference it like $part["c"]. Maybe I can just grab the [c] by using php's key($array)?

Comment: Nice, yeah! I think this is getting somewhere.

$parts = array("c" => array("tableName" => "categories"));
echo key($parts);

Gives me the alias name. Just need to loop through the from parts then and grab the keys and use those. Thanks for your help!